# Работа с Photoshop из программы

Tags: c#, photoshop

Задача такая: есть PSD файл, в нём есть шаблон с текстом и фото, их нужно изменить. Т.е. мне нужно создать приложение в которое вводишь текст и картинку, а оно выдаёт PSD файл, в котором уже заменён текст и картинка.

Такое вообще можно реализовать, например на C#?

Или вообще что-то подобное, что бы можно было работать с файлами фотошопа без фотошопа.

Comment: Тут нужно смотреть в сторону библиотек, которые работают с PSD нативно. Фотошоп тут не причём. Вообще можно и поиском воспользоваться для начала [вот например](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414852/reading-psd-file-format)

Answer (score 0):

Открой текстовым редактором psd и увидишь, что текстовые слои, примитивы и кривые отображаются <тег>, типа формата svg. Копай в эту сторону. Думаю найти тег и заменить содержимое не проблема.

Comment: Я уже пытался так сделать. После редактирования файл в фотошопе не открывается, говоря об ошибке чтения.